# Decompositions of simple, compact Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{k}$ be a simple, compact (in the strict sense, i.e. the Killing form $B$ is negative definite) real Lie algebra.

Can $\mathfrak{k}$ have a direct sum decomposition of the form $\mathfrak{k}=\mathfrak{k}_1\oplus\mathfrak{k}_2$, where each $\mathfrak{k}_i$ is a subalgebra?

In principle I don't see why it shouldn't, but I can't come up with an example.

Comment: Do you want the two subalgebras to commute? If so, each subalgebra is an ideal, so this contradicts simplicity.

Comment: No, not at all. I just want them to be subalgebras. Like the $\mathfrak{k}$, $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{n}$ subalgebras in the Iwasawa decomposition of a (semi)simple algebra, or the $\mathfrak{n}^-$,$\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{n}^+$ in the Cartan triangle decomposition ($\mathfrak{h}$ the Cartan subalgebra).

Comment: In $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ it is not possible, since there is no $2$-dimensional subalgebra. I assume that $\mathfrak{k}_i\neq 0$ here. In $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$ it is possible, but this is not a compact Lie algebra.

Comment: Interesting question. Ideas: Every element of a simple compact Lie algebra is semisimple. I think that implies that every subalgebra is reductive. Since this is stable under scalar extension, one would get a vector space decomposition $\mathfrak{k}_\mathbb{C} = (\mathfrak{k}_1)_\mathbb{C} \oplus (\mathfrak{k}_2)_\mathbb{C}$ where both summands are reductive subalgebras. This seems unlikely, but I don't know how to go on from there.

Comment: Oniščik has classified all decompositions of simple Lie algebras $L$ into the (not necessarily direct) sum of two reductive subalgebras. Reference: [here](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=3643&option_lang=eng), and similar papers. I think, none of these sums for compact simple algebras is direct.